# How to properly serialize spring-data PageImpl without using hateoas/data-rest module

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a simple Spring Boot application that has the next method inside my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<Page> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<User> users = repository.findAll(pageable);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(users);
}
```

My records are being fetched using simple pageable repository. The response generated is:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    }
  ],
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "sorted": false,
      "unsorted": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  },
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalElements": 3,
  "last": true,
  "size": 20,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": {
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
  },
  "numberOfElements": 3,
  "first": true
}
```

How do I achieve same result as when I use ResourceSupport, which is:

```
  .....
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 3,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
```

Reason is - I do not need the links generation and so do not want to deal with the ResourceSupport/Assembler facilities of hateoas.

Is there any built-in option (besides writing my own serialization for Page < T >) ?

Comment: Why are you using a HATEOAS library if you are not interested in links?

Comment: I'm not using hateoas and I don't want to. I'm specifically asked why can't we have Page serialized better without it.